# Change structure of particular array in javascript

Tags: javascript, serializearray

Unfortunately, due to a plugin that I'm using, I have to serialize form names and values in a particular format for them to be saved in a database. Say I have the form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="ratings[check-in]">
    <input type="text" name="ratings[location]">
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="listing_id" value="9297">
</form>
```

currently I'm serializing this as follows:

```
var valueform = $('form#addmyreview').serializeArray();
```

which produces the following structure:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ratings[check-in]
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ratings[location]
            [value] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => listing_id
            [value] => 9483
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => comment
            [value] => 
        )

)
```

However according to the plugin the form data has to be serialised into the following array example:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ratings] => Array
        (
            [check-in] => 
            [location] => 
        )

    [listing_id] => 9297
    [comment] => wedf
)
```

As you can see this is far more succinct and the data can then be used by the plugin. Can anyone help with a way to serialize this object? I have tried the following:

```
function serializeObject(obj) {
    var jsn = {};
    $.each(obj, function() {
        if (jsn[this.name]) {
            if (!jsn[this.name].push) {
                jsn[this.name] = [jsn[this.name]];
            }
            jsn[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            jsn[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return jsn;
};
```

but this produced:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ratings[sanitation] => 
    [ratings[food] => 
    [ratings[reservation-available] => 
    [ratings[wait-time] => 
    [ratings[value] => 
    [ratings[staff-service] => 
    [listing_id] => 9483
    [comment] => 
)
```

so it's a big improvement but not quite there :-(

Comment: Use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead serializeArray to post the form. The output of serialize is the same as you need in the backend.

Comment: @Benilson you're a genius, write that as an answer and ill accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) to post the form. The output of serialize is the same as you need in the backend.

From your output example, I assume your backend language is [PHP](https://www.php.net/), serialize and serializeArray are [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) methods, where serialize is principally used for sending information by [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), see code example below.

Form HTML:

```
<form id="addmyreview">
    <input type="text" name="ratings[check-in]">
    <input type="text" name="ratings[location]">
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="listing_id" value="9297">
</form>
```

Javascript jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#addmyreview').serialize()
}).done(function(result) {
    // do something with result
});
```

In the backend PHP:

```
$data = (object) $_POST;
```